# nexrjs create next-app does create all the required folders

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, next.js

I have installed NextJS using both methods npm install next react react-dom and npx create-next-app appname multiple times, but the directories are supposed to look like:

pages, api(_app.js, index.js), public, styles, .next, node_modules

But in MY project they look like: node_modules, yarn.lock, package.json

I saw multiple installation procedures but they all give the same project directories (latter) TO ME, and the former directories in their tutorials. I cannot follow any tutorials on nextjs due to this! I have re-installed yarn and nodejs several times, but it still didn't work.

Comment: So you are saying that other directories are not created, is it?

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry about yarn or node, if you're using npx it's always going to be the latest version. The best advice I can give you is double and triple check you are running it in the folder you think you are. I just ran it to check and there's nothing wrong with next. Here's the steps.

```
cd folderJustAboveWhereIWant
npx create-next-app myAppNameHere
cd myAppNameHere
npm run start
```

And wahla... The pretty cool looking next starter page should pop on port I think 8080? If you need help along the way reach out directly if stack allows it.

Comment: I have tried in this way but still it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

By installing next app multiple times you made yourself confusion!
Now make a new folder:

step 1 : open powershell window there

step 2 : download yarn if you do not have downloaded, it is too faster and simpler than npm/npx

step 3 : run command `yarn create next-app`

step 4 : it will ask for project name in terminal.

And that's it! your next app is created!
To run the next app run command `yarn run dev`
And again I would like to recommend you to download yarn for next apps, it will surely give a blow to your next app!
Happy Coding!

Comment: I created a new folder and did exactly whatever you stated, but still nothing worked. There are still many folders missing.

Comment: which folders are missing?

Comment: public, pages, styles, .next, .gitignore folders are missing.

Comment: This is actually very concerning I will recommend you to watch the video of CodeWithHarry which I have attched to clarify your steps!                                                                [Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ne_h515wcv4&list=PLu0W_9lII9agtWvR_TZdb_r0dNI8-lDwG&index=2)

Answer (score 0):

it's because you set "Use App Router" to yes during installation.

https://nextjs.org/docs/app

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).